# How to properly Serialize/Deserialize an ArrayList with Custom Objects?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm learning how to serialize in Java

my problem I'm having is the code works but I get warnings, I think it's the way I cast it.
I'm worried it will give me a problem as I progress.

> Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList warning.

I'm trying to create a account registrations for my simple project.

```
public class BankAccount implements Serializable {
    
    public String username;
    public String password;
    
     public BankAccount() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public BankAccount(String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    } 
}
```

Serialization

```
BankAccount acc1 = new BankAccount("myuser", "mypass");
BankAccount acc2 = new BankAccount("abcd" , "1234");
BankAccount acc3 = new BankAccount("useracbc" , "pw1234");
ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
accounts.add(acc1);
accounts.add(acc2);
accounts.add(acc3);
try {
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("account.ser");
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
out.writeObject(accounts);
out.close();
System.out.println("Account successfully serialized");
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Deserialization

```
ArrayList<BankAccount> myList = null;
try {
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("account.ser");
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
myList = (ArrayList<BankAccount>) in.readObject();

fileIn.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
for(BankAccount list: myList) {
System.out.println(list.username);
System.out.println(list.password);
}
```

I tried this one from [howtodoinjava](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/arraylist/serialize-deserialize-arraylist/) but I still get the same warning from the casting.

```
ArrayList<Employee> employeesList = null;

try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("employeeData");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);) {

  employeesList = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();

} catch (IOException ioe) {
  ioe.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
  System.out.println("Class not found");
  c.printStackTrace();
}

//Verify list data
for (Employee employee : employeesList) {
  System.out.println(employee);
}
```

Comment: Those warnings are unavoidable -- you have to make an assumption about what type of object is in the file -- you could read an Object  and then do an instance check, but if it's not an ArrayList then something is wrong anyway.

By the way: you should remove all of those `catch` blocks and just let the exception bubble up to the next level. Catching and ignoring exceptions will cause you problems in the future.

Comment: Those warnings are *not* unavoidable. Just put the annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the method.

Comment: @user207421 That does not solve the problem.  In fact, it creates worse problems.  Just because `@SuppressWarnings` allows the code to compile doesn’t mean the code is safe or reliable.

Comment: @VGR *What* problem? The code is correct if the incoming data is of the right class, and if it isn’t you will get a class cast exception. *That’s how the system is designed.*

Comment: @user207421 Yes, you’ll get a ClassCastException… much later, when retrieving elements from the List, where there is no obvious connection to the unchecked cast.  Certainly not at the moment the deserialized object is cast to a typed ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is there because the cast cannot be verified by the compiler, and there is no runtime checks either. So the warning is valid, the only advice is:

**Do not** simply cast an `ArrayList` with a specific Generic to your target type. Because of the way [Generics work in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you might now have a `ArrayList<MyObject>` but nothing guarantees that it also holds **just** `MyObject`s. It could hold any `Object` and you'll only notice when trying to access it.

**Use** encapsulation - so have your own class that keeps explicit references (without Generics). If you serialize that, you just have **one** check only (If you do not want the warning) or you get the `ClassCastException` when loading the data.

And also be aware: Serialization to JSON or XML (using libraries like Jackson, gson, ...) might be much better in most situations.

Quick test that shows, that you get an `ClassCastException` **when accessing** the elements if you simply did a cast on `ArrayList`. (The reason behind this is the generic type erasure.)

So a quick unit test that shows the `ClassCastException` when accessing the element of the `ArrayList`:

```java
package de.kneitzel.so;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class BinarySerializationFailure {

    @Test
    public void testBinarySerialization() {
        ArrayList<String> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        objects.add("Some String");

        try ( FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("account.ser");
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut)) {
            out.writeObject(objects);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            fail("Exception!", ex);
        }

        ArrayList<Point> loadedList = null;
        try (
                FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("account.ser");
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn)) {
            loadedList = (ArrayList<Point>) in.readObject();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            fail("Exception!", ex);
        }

        // Assert, that we was able to load the data.
        assertEquals(1, loadedList.size());

        // So whenever we try to access, we get an exception:
        ArrayList<Point> finalLoadedList = loadedList;
        assertThrows(ClassCastException.class, () -> {
            Point point = finalLoadedList.get(0);
        });
    }
}
```

I hope that it is now easier to understand because I didn't put important wording below the code.

Comment: Your test shows that you *correctly* get a `ClassCastException` when there is a class casting error. XML, JSON, &c will behave the same way, This is not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: I think you simply missed the important point, that you do not get the ClassCastException when loading the data.

And of course: The user asked for getting rid of the warning. And that was already handled in the other answer that gave me only downvotes.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding unchecked warning: One solution could be to simply do the checks first:

But with the generic type erasure, you have to check the ArrayList type and also all elements. So the code with checks could be something like:

```
    ArrayList<Employee> employeesList = new ArrayList<>();

    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("employeeData");
         ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);) {

        Object readObject = ois.readObject();
        if (readObject instanceof ArrayList readArray) {
            for (Object element: readArray) {
                if (element instanceof Employee employee) {
                    employeesList.add(employee);
                } else {
                    // Handle here, that your are loading a file that is not what expected, e.g. throw an exception.
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Handle here, that your are loading a file that is not what expected, e.g. throw an exception.
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
        System.out.println("Class not found");
        c.printStackTrace();
    }
```

That way you only do checked casts. And be aware: I did no error handling. You should handle the case that the read object is not an ArrayList or does not contain Employee elements.

So this could be valid solution to get rid of the warning. But that is not a solution I would recommend!

Instead: Create your own class Employees. That will store the List internally and will also contain all code required to access the Employees. That way you write an instance of that class and you only have to check one instanceOf instead of checking all employees.

Comment: And maybe you want to drop binary serialization and use a library to write json or xml instead using libraries like jackson or gson?

Comment: The problem is not checking the type before cast, the problem is that you are silently ignoring possible errors, leading to more problems down the line. Just one possible example - you read from the wrong file and you end up with an empty employee list, instead of having a 1000 of them. The next time you write the list to the file (the correct file now) it will contain only the new data. Now you have lost all data for those 1000 employees.

Comment: Ok, but that is mainly to keep the code short. Of course you have to do something with an else on each if. 
So you really think that is a reason for a downvote? Instead of simply mentioning something like that? This minor issue is easy to edit if required.

Thank you for your comment, I will edit my answer but please understand that I really find it funny when "Those warnings are unavoidable" gets upvotes...

Comment: Just saw while editing: "And be aware: I did no error handling. You should handle the case that the read object is not an ArrayList or does not contain Employee elements." So I even mentioned that ... so yeah - I love this great community ... And I am glad that I was able to learn, that "Those warnings are unavoidable" ... Have a nice day.

Comment: You yourself `Just saw while editing`, and you wrote the answer - the 'disclaimer' is barely visible, I didn't see it either. People tend to just copy/paste code, and while I firmly believe that it's their responsibility to check the code and read carefully what is written, they don't do it mostly. The answer should be written in a way that the pitfalls are clear to see (if there are any). For me that's enough of a reason to downvote. After the edit, I am retracting the downvote.

Comment: And that's just my opinion, but those if-else, just to throw another type of exception are redundant and make the code harder to read. What if we have something more complicated, like `Map<Key, Value>`, check if every entry key and value are of correct type with if-else? Or something custom with even more generic parameters? Just suppress the warnings and write a unit test that you are loading the correct thing - code is easier to read and no chance for runtime exceptions happening.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond and sorry if I was a little upset. And I agree fully: You do not do that. But the core issue is, that you do not simply have such data in an ArrayList or Map or whatever and directly binary serialize it. If you have such data you also have code to manage it. So with an object oriented language you encapsulate the data which means you have one class with the data and you serialize that class. So it is one simple check / cast. (Which I also mentioned in my post).

Comment: And you are aware, that no checks are done on elements, when you cast the ArrayList? So you end up with an ArrayList<Employee> but you could have non Employee elements. So you get the ClassCastException when you access the element.

So in my eyes, simply casting the ArrayList is NEVER a good idea. A shame that I cannot add Code in here - so now I am thinking about collecting more Downvotes through posting another answer that shows that problem.

Comment: Ok, quick and dirt test put inside an github project:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kneitzel/java-forum-algorithms/SO-78213265/src/test/java/de/kneitzel/so/BinarySerializationFailure.java

With simply casting the ArrayList you simply risk ClassCastExceptions when accessing the data. You the risk is a runtime exception anywhere else in your code when you simply cast the ArrayList!

Answer (score -1):

1. Custom objects implement the Serializable API
2. Handling transient keywords: If there are properties in your class that you don't want to be serialized, you can tag them with transient keywords.
3. Use ObjectOutputStream to serialize the ArrayList to a file and ObjectInputStream to deserialize from a file.
4. A serialVersionUID is explicitly declared in the class, Preventing class structure changes that cause deserialization to fail
5. About the Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList warning, you can use the try-with-resources statement introduced in Java 7 can be combined with the instanceof check
6. This kind of warning is acceptable, but adding type-checking makes the code more robust